# Python: How to find path to the script running a python script

Tags: python, path

Lets say i have a python script at `homedir/codes/py/run.py`
I also have a bash script at `homedir/codes/run.sh`
This bash script runs `run.py` by `python py/run.py`.

The thing is that i need to be able to find out, in `run.py`, the path to the calling script `run.sh`. If `run.sh` is run from its own directory, i can just use `os.getcwd()`. But `run.sh` can in principle be run from anywhere, and then `os.getcwd()` will return the path to where `run.sh` is run FROM, and not the actual location of `run.sh`.

ex:

- At `homedir/codes`: `./run.sh` -> `os.getcwd()` returns `homedir/codes`
- At `homedir`: `./codes/run.sh` -> `os.getcwd()` returns `homedir`

But i want `homedir/codes` no matter how `run.sh` is called. Is this possible?

Comment: What should happen if the Python script is run directly from an interactive shell, not from `run.sh`?

Comment: If the bash scripts contains nothing but `python py/run.py`, it must be run from `homedir/codes` otherwise `py/run.py` wouldn't be found. So your question is not complete.

Comment: Oh, sorry i didn't think this through enough. I guess i'll have to assume run.sh is run from its own directory, or else the relative path to run.py won't work (as you say).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the absolute path of the current script in bash, do:

```
SCRIPT=$(readlink -f "$0")
```

Now, pass that variable as the last argument to the python script.  You can get the argument from python as:

```
sys.argv[-1]
```

Comment: Another way of getting the current directory of the running bash script (with dirname command within backticks): 

SCRIPT='dirname $0'

Comment: This mostly works, but is nonportable, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028. `$0`, like all parameters, should always be quoted.

Comment: If you don't want to pass parameters, it should also be possible to set the directory you want in the shell wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

you can get the absolute qualified path with:

```
os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.curdir))
```

Comment: This isn't want the OP wants.

Comment: It is what I was Googling for :-)

Comment: This same as `pwd -P` This is not the path of the script. This is the path of the user.